# Flask serving images locally, but not once deployed to Google App Engine

Tags: flask, google-app-engine

A flask app is serving a bunch of `.js`/`.css`/image files from the `/static` folder. It is deployed to Google App Engine behind Cloudflare.

I have no problem processing `.js` and `.css` files - they are served with no errors both locally and when deployed. Also the images from the `/static/icons` folder that have been added previously seem to be served ok.

I'm adding a new image file to the `/static` folder and it serves normally locally but when I deploy the app to Google App Engine it returns a 404 error.

What I tried:

- Checked to source hosted at Google App Engine -- the file is there.
- Tried both `.png` and `.webp` extensions
- Turning Cloudflare cache off (development mode)
- Adding the `handlers` section to the `app.yaml`:

```
handlers:
  - url: /static
    static_dir: static
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please check if the [following link](https://sites.google.com/site/usfcomputerscience/loading-images-and-css-in-appengine) helps you?

Comment: Thanks, but this setting `handlers` in `app.yaml` is one of the things I already tried to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cloud storage for serving static files. Please check the following [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/serving-static-files) about how to implement it.

Comment: No, I prefer to keep them inside my app file structure. This includes them into the version control and gives better overall visibility of the whole app.